# What to look for when buying a USB flash drive for booting?

Tags: boot, usb, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

I wanted to make an USB-stick bootable and had some problems with that, Windows 10 wouldn't allow to format it to fat32 and neither did Ubuntu.

What kind of USB Flash drive should I look for when I buy a new one? Would be nice if it was formatted as fat32 already.

Also should a USB drive have a partition table to be bootable or not?

Comment: How is it even possible to kill a flash drive by doing that?

Comment: Idk. I formatted them a few times using ubuntu and windows and at least one stick (which is a cheap one to be fair) doesn't work anymore at all. It only shows up as empty drive...

Comment: Your problem isn't anything you did to the drives.  You should be able to partition and format it and make it bootable.  Note that if your Windows is an older version, it will only recognize the first primary partition on a removable drive.  Flash drives are not very reliable and there is a lot of crap on the market.  So if one or two died while you were doing normal things to them, don't assume it was your fault.

Comment: I mean i guess i can trust Kingston? got that one to work with rufus on Windows 10 (but it's write protected now and I have no clue how I could remove that protection). Also I don't know if several reformats can be considered normal. But anywys, thank you @fixer1234

Comment: Write protection is something that happens when flash drives fail.  When they aren't able to save new content (e.g., too many bad blocks and all the spare blocks are exhausted, or other failures), they go into write protect mode to allow you to get your files off before the drive dies completely.  A flash drive should be good for thousands of writes to each location.  A few reformats shouldn't kill it.  If the drive is relatively new, the company might replace it under warranty.

Comment: I don't know if I still have warranty on that drive but it's not older than a year, that's why it surprises me that it seems to die already. But for some reason that only happens when formatted as fat32. Didn't seem to happen with ntfs or exfat.

Comment: Fat32 isn't a great format because it has a filesize limit of 4 GB.  If you're having problems with that but not other formats, it's no big loss.  Just use exfat.

Comment: Does exfat work with booting though? I heard only FAT32 works for that.